# How to provide own grammar to check class tree in SonarQube?

Tags: sonarqube

I am trying to build a language plugin for SonarQube. I modified the java language plugin to convert into my own plugin. I want to put some of my own grammar to check the class structure as:

```
public **with sharing** class abc{

}
```

How can I do that? I am modifying java plugin 2.2 .

Comment: It is not really clear what you want to achieve : you want to generate an Syntax Tree of your own language to then check things in this tree ?

Comment: yes ,something like that. for example - In java, class definition is like - public class abc { // class implementation } and in my code I would like to check - public with sharing class abc { // class implementation }. I want to check that with my plugin.